# How can I set log4net appender to Wcf service?

Tags: wcf, log4net

I want to configure appender that will send logs to wcf service.

I've already service in the air that can get logs at address "http://localhost:8080" with method '`Get logs(string log);`'

I need help how to configure the appender in order to send logs to this service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searches, I got it, and it's so easy to implement. So I wrote a post for this with sample code to download available:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/wcf_appender_for_log4net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built-in one, but you can make your own WCF appender like this guy did (or use his) http://blog.joachim.at/?p=31